# er diagram, one to many/many to many

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram

[image: ER diagram]

I try to make a er diagram, and my professor told me that the the er diagram still only support one product per order, how can i make the order support multiple products?

the image link is in the description

Comment: I think in my Order table, Order ID and Order Number is probably maybe the same thing and I maybe I should delete one of them..?

Comment: The assumption is that each customer can make multiple order, each supplier can supply multiple products.

Comment: Instead of having conversation with yourself in the comments you should just edit your question to improve it. That makes it easier for the reader of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `OrderLine` entity:

```
Order ID
Product ID
Weight(lb)
Promotion
Price
```

You should also remove everything except `Order ID` and `Customer ID` from `Order`.

For each product you want to add to an order you add an `OrderLine` that links the `Product ID` and the `Order ID`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your prof is right. Remove the ProductId from the Order entity and add OrderId to Priduct entity.